# Expedited inventory retrieval with Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

Glacier is cheap as long as you are OK with slow retrievals, and if needed you can use the "Expedited" mode to retrieve archives faster, but at a cost.

See: [Retrieving Amazon Glacier Archives - Amazon Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive-two-steps.html#api-downloading-an-archive-two-steps-retrieval-options)

However this mode doesn't seem available for inventory retrievals. Is there any way to avoid waiting 4-5 hours to get the inventory of a Glacier vault?